# Recycle view FlexboxLayoutManger issue

Tags: android-recyclerview, horizontal-scrolling, android-flexboxlayout

After scrolling the Recycle view and moving from one fragment to another when you come back to same fragment recycleview is not getting visible
(using recycle view with FlexboxLayoutManger)

Recycle view is working fine with LinearlayoutManager